# Parent component not listening to custom event in VUE2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

This is the main html file where the Vue compont is included

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> -->

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

    <div id= "root">
      {{message}}
      <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
      <div class = "col-md-6">
        <question-container :question = 'details' ><question-container>
      </div>
      <div class ="col-md-3"></div>
          <!-- <mcq-behaviour :data = "details[0]"></mcq-behaviour> -->
    </div>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**parent component**

```
Vue.component('questionContainer',{
  props:['question'],
  template : ` <div><div v-on:nextQuestion = "updateQuestion()">{{question}}<mcq-behaviour :data = "question[x]"></mcq-behaviour></div></div>`, 
  data : function() { 
    return {x :0}
  },
  methods: {
    updateQuestion : function(){
      alert("Hi");
    }
  }
})
```

**child component**

```
Vue.component('mcqBehaviour', {
  props: ['data'],
  template: `   
    <div class= "mngMrgin">
      <div class="panel panel-primary" >
        <div class="panel-heading">Question</div>
        <div class="panel-body">{{data.question}}</div>
      </div>
      <div v-for = "(opt,i) in data.options">
        <div class="well well-sm" >{{opt.text}}</div>
      </div>
      <div class ="row">    
        <div class="col-md-4"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" v-on:click = "previousQuestion()">Previous</button></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" v-on:click = "checkAnswer()">Check Answer</button></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" v-on:click = "nextPress()">NEXT</button></div>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  `,
  methods : {
    nextPress : function(){
      this.$emit('nextQuestion');       
    }
  }
})
```

**App**

```
var app= new Vue({
  el : '#root',
  data: {
    message: "Hello from Vue",
    details : [
      {
        "_id": "5927f07c3c1501cd533519d6",
        "options": [
          {'text' : 'answer1',id : 1},
          {'text' : 'answer2' ,id : 2 },
          {'text' : 'answer3',id : 3},
          {'text' : 'answer4' ,id : 4},
        ],
        "question": "Hello, undefined! You have 2 unread messages.",
        "correctAnsid" : 1
      },{
        "_id": "5927f07c3c1501cd53351956",
        "options": [
          {'text' : 'answer1',id : 1},
          {'text' : 'answer2' ,id : 2 },
          {'text' : 'answer3',id : 3},
          {'text' : 'answer4' ,id : 4},
        ],
        "question": "Hello, undefined! You have 3 unread messages.",
        "correctAnsid" : 4
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The parent component is not listening to the custom event UpdateQuestion being emitted from the child component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid using camel cased events.  Try

```
this.$emit('next-question')
```

Also your listener needs to be added to the component itself, not an element containing the component.

```
<div>{{question}}
  <mcq-behaviour v-on:next-question = "updateQuestion()" :data = "question[x]"></mcq-behaviour>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. that solved my problem.But Can you tell me Why we should avoid camel cased events??

Comment: @DevarshiRoy You should avoid camel cased events because attributes in HTML (`v-on:some-event`) are case-insensitive. Vue will show a warning in the console, "Note that HTML attributes are case-insensitive and you cannot use v-on to listen to camelCase events when using in-DOM templates. You should probably use "camel-cased" instead of "camelCased""

Comment: @DevarshiRoy Also, this being your very first question on SO, if the answer was helpful, solved your problem, you should accept/upvote.

Comment: I have upvoted but when i press the upvote arrow it is showing a message saying that as I have less than 15 reputation it will not publicly change the displayed post score although it has been recorded.Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DevarshiRoy Yup, you wont be able to upvote until you get some more rep, but accept is available to you. It's the checkmark next to answers.